# Cassini exception unhandeld

Tags: asp.net, exception, cassini

I am getting an exception thrown by the ASP.NET Development Web Server "Type is not resolved for member 'Model.AppIdentity,Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"
It works fine in IIS6.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be an issue with Cassini and serialization exception when implementing IIdentity interface. 
Here is a post about it
[Cassini&SerializationException](http://www.leandrodg.com.ar/blog/2007/12/cassini-serializationexception-type-is-not-resolved-for-member/)

If that is your case, a workaround could be to make your class implementing IIdentity to inherit from MarshalByRefObject.